# Switch images based on client geography, zip code, location?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, geocode

My issue is a simple one, but the solution may not be. My company has several franchise locations all over the country. We have been building separate "minisites" for each location; however, we would like to simply geocode our main site to be able to deliver geographically-pertinent content based on the user's location. For instance, our main phone number is in the header - if someone visits the site from a location across the country, the phone number switches to a local number to them. The same thing with images - how would we switch images based on a user's zip code or location? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what part of this you're stuck at. Surely you don't expect someone to just hand you a chunk of PHP that will do this from beginning to end.

Comment: I don't have any idea as to how complicated something like this would be, and I'm simply hoping for some advice or some direction as where to begin.

Comment: I'd start by decomposing the problem until you arrive at a sequence of steps you need to realise, then trying to implement those, then asking more specific questions about problems you encounter.

Comment: I'm sorry - I guess I don't pre-qualify to ask the question then. I have never done this before as far as making my code geographically aware in this manner. I guess the simplest question that wouldn't be asking too much to answer would be, "can it be done?"

Comment: @BenMcCoy - if you can figure out how to identify a user's zip code or location, then it's do-able. I've no idea how you can identify a user's location automatically, though - would you be happy with an initial screen that just asked "where in the country are you?"

Comment: @BenMcCoy It's doable. You can use a service like [GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location) or [HTML5 geolocation](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html) to get positioning information, then work from there. ("Work from there" is the tricky part that's heavily dependent on how the rest of your app works, you need to somehow map locations to the various bits of data with geographical alternatives.) Also keep in mind that geolocation that doesn't use a GPS sensor isn't reliable, so you should make the data for other locations accessible.

Comment: Also, don't use a "where are you" screen, that's the multinational corp's equivalent of the Flash intro. Unless it's vitally important that the user never spots the wrong data you're just delaying visitors from seeing your site.

Comment: ok thanks for the input - now I have somewhere to start from. Might be a good solution andrewsi - thanks.

Comment: To clarify: don't use a "where are you screen" as the start of your site. If it's after clicking a "where to find / how to contact us" link, it might be okay.

Comment: I always prefer a "Current Location: " message at the top which let's you change the region by entering zip, city name etc. into a text field.

Answer (score 0):

1) determine users location.

This can be done many ways, you may want to check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

2) create a simple database of image names vs zipcodes

3) once you've determined the zipcode in step 1, query the database to get the image filename, then use php to place the correct image on the screen.

(its way more complicated than this of course, but these are the basic steps)